# Is there another way to use these css styles, especially focus

Tags: html, css

There's some problem with my css focus code. I wanted to change the background color when the class is selected but when I click, it changes the color but it doesn't maintain the changes. It just disappears and appears, like `hover`.

CSS Code

```css
.reward:focus, 
.reward:active,
div.reward a:focus,
div.reward a:active,
.reward:focus .rdesc,
.reward:active .rdesc,
.reward:focus .rnumb,
.reward:active .rnumb,
.reward:focus .rnumbi, 
.reward:active .numbi,
.reward:focus .rtitle,
.reward:active .rtitle
{  
    background:yellow;   
}
```

HTML Code

```html
<div class="cfrewards">
    <div class="reward_title pull-center">title</div>
    <div class="reward">
        <a href="javascript: void(0);" class="reward-amount">
            <span class="ramount">
                <input type="radio" name="reward" value="3" data-id="97" class="reward-amount-radio" />
                description
            </span>
            <span class="rtitle">title</span>
            <span class="rdesc">description</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Michael just because the OP's english isn't the best, it does not mean you should mock him/her. If you really want to help then paste the code into a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like

```html
<input type="radio" name="reward" value="3" id="reward-amount-radio" />
<label for="reward-amount-radio">
    description
    <span class="rtitle">title</span>
    <span class="rdesc">description</span>
</label>
```

```css
#reward-amount-radio {
    float: left;
}
#reward-amount-radio + label {  
    display: block;
}
#reward-amount-radio:checked + label {  
    background:yellow;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/t39cyo5r/2/)

Comment: This works but i dont want to change just the title , i wants to change the div background. 
Something like this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/g0k3oeov/)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ecb86gLw/

use :checked

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
background:yellow;   
}
```